# Extracting data from Google search results

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I want to make program that extracts search results given by Google and save them into a text file.

For Example:

In this picture I want to save the data "New York ,NY,USA Thursday 11:0 PM Cloudy 13 C Precipitation:36% Humidity:90% Wind 8 KM/h" in a text file

[image]

Similarly, in this picture I want to save "1.8m" in a text file.

[image]

So, I would like to ask that is it even possible? if yes then how?

Edit :  I tried the following code given below.

The xhr.response gives the source code of the page which does not contain the data i want and the xhr.responseURL gives the URL of google itself . The data i need is in the XHR response /URL which i cant seem to get. Anyone has any other ideas of how to do this or it is impossible?.

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.responseType = 'text';
xhr.open('GET', 'https://www.google.com.pk/webhp?sourceid=chrome
instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=real+madrid', true);
xhr.onload = function () {
console.log(xhr.response);
console.log(xhr.responseURL);
};
xhr.send(null);
```

Comment: use PHP to get and scrape the content you wish to "borrow" from google

Comment: Show your efforts

Comment: well.... i don't have any because i haven't started it yet. so that's why  I asked if it was possible or not before starting it .
I did simple searches like finding the results in the source code of the webpage(which i couldn't)  but i could find them in the "inspect " feature of chrome. So I was wondering that how would it even be possible to get the data if i couldn't even find the code ?

Comment: JavaScript can generate HTML on the fly. The HTML source and the 'elements' tab in Chrome inspector are the before and after versions, respectively. You probably want to look for the data in Ajax calls under the network tab.

Comment: Couldn't you do a wget for the data into a variable or some other data structure and then parse the contents with a regex to get the data you need? (from the html content)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Google Knowledge Graph API

https://developers.google.com/knowledge-graph/

you need to create a API key for that